# Fetch .json with AngularJS $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, ngresource

So I have a web server that is handling my .json files.

On the client side a have a simple service :

```
var service = angular.module('services.service', ['ngResource']);

service.factory('Service', ['$resource',

    function($resource){
        return $resource('json/:serviceId.json', {},
            {

            }
        );

    }
]);
```

but when I call it from the controller :

```
$scope.service = Service.get({serviceId : id} );
```

I don't get anything written into the $scope.service

I've checked my network, and the .json file arrives, but is not handled?

Don't know what to do

Comment: Is the JSON malformed? can you post it here? Also you can try to catch errors `Service.get({serviceId: id}).$promise.then(console.log,console.log);`

Comment: Thnx man, you saved me, it was malformed. Lost an hour on this sh*t. Post a answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON could be malformed.  You can look at the response from the call in more detail by logging it:

```
Service.get({serviceId: id}).$promise['finally'](console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in controller.

```
 Service.get({serviceId : id} ).$promise.then(function(d){
    $scope.service = d;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    })
```